# Java Awt & Swing

Tags: java, swing, jframe, awt, pong

Pong.Java

```
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.awt.event.KeyEvent;
import java.awt.event.KeyListener;

import javax.swing.JFrame;

public class Pong {
    private static final int WIDTH = 900, HEIGHT = 700;
    JFrame win = new JFrame();
    Paddle paddleOne = new Paddle(1);
    Paddle paddleTwo = new Paddle(2);
    Graphics g;

    Pong(){
        init();
    }

    void init(){
        win.setTitle("PONG");
        win.setSize(WIDTH, HEIGHT);
        win.addKeyListener(keyListener);
        win.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
        win.getContentPane().setBackground(Color.black);
        win.setVisible(true);
        win.getContentPane().validate();
        win.repaint();
    }


    public void paintComponent(Graphics g){
        g.setColor(Color.white);
        g.fillRect(paddleOne.getX(), paddleOne.getY(), paddleOne.getHEIGHT(), paddleOne.getWIDTH());

        System.out.println("drawn");
    }

    KeyListener keyListener = new KeyListener() {
        public void keyPressed(KeyEvent e) {
            int key = e.getKeyCode();

            switch(key){
            case 87:
                System.out.println("Player 1 Up");
                break;
            case 83:
                System.out.println("Player 1 Down");
                break;
            case 38:
                System.out.println("Player 2 Up");
                break;
            case 40:
                System.out.println("Player 2 Down");
                break;
            }

            win.getContentPane().validate();
            win.repaint();

        }

        public void keyReleased(KeyEvent arg0) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        }

        public void keyTyped(KeyEvent arg0) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        }

    };

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Pong p = new Pong();
    }
}
```

Paddle.Java

```
public class Paddle{
private int WIDTH = 50, HEIGHT = 150, X, Y;


int playerNum;

Paddle(int playerNum){
    if(playerNum == 1){
        X = 10;
        Y = 10;
    }else if (playerNum == 2){
        X = 500;
        Y = 10;
    }
}

public void setX(int x){
    X = x;
}

public void setY(int y){
    Y = y;
}

public int getWIDTH() {
    return WIDTH;
}

public int getHEIGHT() {
    return HEIGHT;
}

public int getX() {
    return X;
}

public int getY() {
    return Y;
}

}
```

I'm relatively new to Java programming, or more specifically Awt & Swing, what my question is, why isn't my rectangle drawing? Any help is appreciated. Thank you so much!

Comment: `public void paintComponent(Graphics g){`  Try adding `@Override` notation..

Comment: The method paintComponent(Graphics) of type Pong must override or implement a supertype method is what it's throwing at me.

Comment: So `Pong` extends from nothing and is suppose to "magically" be paintable? Have a look at [Painting in AWT and Swing](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/painting-140037.html) and [Performing Custom Painting](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/painting/) for more details about how painting is suppose to work in Swing

Comment: Yep.. what @MadProgrammer said.

Answer (score 1):

You need to overriding `paintComponents` to draw.
Here is your Pong.java

```
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.awt.event.KeyEvent;
import java.awt.event.KeyListener;

import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.SwingUtilities;

public class Pong {
    private static final int WIDTH = 900, HEIGHT = 700;
    JFrame win = new JFrame();
    Paddle paddleOne = new Paddle(1);
    Paddle paddleTwo = new Paddle(2);
    Graphics g;

    Pong() {
        init();
    }

    void init() {
        win.setTitle("PONG");
        win.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        win.setSize(WIDTH, HEIGHT);
        win.addKeyListener(keyListener);
        win.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
        win.add(new Panel(paddleOne));
        win.getContentPane().setBackground(Color.black);
        win.setVisible(true);
        win.getContentPane().validate();
        win.repaint();
    }

    KeyListener keyListener = new KeyListener() {
        public void keyPressed(KeyEvent e) {
            int key = e.getKeyCode();

            switch (key) {
            case 87:
                System.out.println("Player 1 Up");
                break;
            case 83:
                System.out.println("Player 1 Down");
                break;
            case 38:
                System.out.println("Player 2 Up");
                break;
            case 40:
                System.out.println("Player 2 Down");
                break;
            }

            win.getContentPane().validate();
            win.repaint();

        }

        public void keyReleased(KeyEvent arg0) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        }

        public void keyTyped(KeyEvent arg0) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        }

    };

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {

            @Override
            public void run() {
                new Pong();

            }
        });
    }
}
```

Here  Panel.java in where `paintComponent` overridden.

```
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Graphics;
import javax.swing.JPanel;

public class Panel extends JPanel{
    private Paddle paddleOne;
    public Panel(Paddle pdl) {
        paddleOne = pdl;
    }

    @Override
    public void paintComponent(Graphics g){
        super.paintComponent(g);
        g.setColor(Color.white);
        g.fillRect(paddleOne.getX(), paddleOne.getY(), paddleOne.getHEIGHT(), paddleOne.getWIDTH());

        //System.out.println("drawn");   //Should not put something here which may overhead.
    }

}
```

Comment: You've broken the requirements of the paint chain for one.  You really should be starting the UI from within the context of the EDT, but I'd question creating a frame from within a instance method of a panel, but that's a design issue and I doubt the key events will trigger reliably while I'm pocking holes in it. While it's nice to provide a runnable solution, you should lead the horse to water, not shove it's head under it ;)

Comment: @MadProgrammer, is it ok?

Answer (score 1):

In order for something to be painted within in Swing, it first must extend from something Swing know's how to paint, this commonly means a `JComponent` (or more typically a `JPanel`).

Then you can override one of the paint methods, which is called by the painting subsystem, in this case, it's generally preferred to override `paintComponent`, but don't forget to call `super.paintComponent` before you do any custom painting, or you're setting yourself up for some weird and generally unpredictable painting issues.

Take a look at [Painting in AWT and Swing](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/painting-140037.html) and [Performing Custom Painting](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/painting/) for more details.

```
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.EventQueue;
import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.awt.event.KeyEvent;
import java.awt.event.KeyListener;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.UIManager;
import javax.swing.UnsupportedLookAndFeelException;

public class Pongo {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new Pongo();
    }

    public Pongo() {
        EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                try {
                    UIManager.setLookAndFeel(UIManager.getSystemLookAndFeelClassName());
                } catch (ClassNotFoundException | InstantiationException | IllegalAccessException | UnsupportedLookAndFeelException ex) {
                    ex.printStackTrace();
                }

                JFrame frame = new JFrame("Testing");
                frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
                frame.add(new PongPane());
                frame.pack();
                frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
                frame.setVisible(true);
            }
        });
    }

    public class PongPane extends JPanel {

        private static final int WIDTH = 900, HEIGHT = 700;
        Paddle paddleOne = new Paddle(1);
        Paddle paddleTwo = new Paddle(2);

        public PongPane() {
            setBackground(Color.BLACK);
        }

        @Override
        public void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
            super.paintComponent(g);
            g.setColor(Color.white);
            g.fillRect(paddleOne.getX(), paddleOne.getY(), paddleOne.getHEIGHT(), paddleOne.getWIDTH());

            //System.out.println("drawn");   //Should not put something here which may overhead.
        }

    }

    public class Paddle {

        private int WIDTH = 50, HEIGHT = 150, X, Y;

        int playerNum;

        Paddle(int playerNum) {
            if (playerNum == 1) {
                X = 10;
                Y = 10;
            } else if (playerNum == 2) {
                X = 500;
                Y = 10;
            }
        }

        public void setX(int x) {
            X = x;
        }

        public void setY(int y) {
            Y = y;
        }

        public int getWIDTH() {
            return WIDTH;
        }

        public int getHEIGHT() {
            return HEIGHT;
        }

        public int getX() {
            return X;
        }

        public int getY() {
            return Y;
        }
    }
}
```

I would also discourage the use of `KeyListener` within this context and inside advice the use of the key bindings API, it doesn't suffer from the same focus related issues that `KeyListener` does.  See [How to Use Key Bindings](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/misc/keybinding.html) for more details